# I can't add a repository

Tags: repository

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ppsspp/stable
ppsspp/stable
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.qYp0cz3xW2 --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys
```

Comment: There is no error. The repository is added.

Comment: but it doesn't work

Comment: What is there? How to fix it?

Comment: And why do you think that it does not work?

Comment: $ sudo apt-get update W: Не удалось получить http://ppa.launchpad.net/ppsspp/stable/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

Comment: Lucid is too old and not longer supported. Upgrade to Trusty or Vivid.

Comment: I have installed Linux mint 17

Comment: Linux Mint is also off-topic here, sorry :\

Answer (score 1):

You want to add a repository which does not provide your Ubuntu version. It looks like you have **Lucid** installed. Upgrade your Ubuntu first, for instance **Vivid** is supported in the repository.
Check the repository yourself by opening following link in a browser and see which versions are supported:

http://ppa.launchpad.net/ppsspp/stable/ubuntu/dists/